# How to optimize the most frequent MySQL SELECT query

Tags: mysql, select

I have a MySQL table with millions of records, and there are hundreds of records inserted into the table every day.

In the front-end, it displays the most recent 100 records using the query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
table_a 
ORDER BY creation_time DESC 
LIMIT 100
```

Every time a user visits the page, it will scan through the large table and perform the sorting. The procedure looks very resources consuming.

I find that there is a `VIEW` in MySQL. Does it help to optimize the performance if I create a view to store the results? Is the `view`  synchronized with the original table? Or any other means to boost the query performance?

Thanks!

Comment: Views typically slow things down. Focus on indexes to start. And review whether or not you need all those rows hanging around.

Comment: In reference to @Drew's point:  you can add an index on `creation_time`. `ALTER TABLE `table_a` ADD INDEX `idx_table_a_creation_time` (`creation_time`)`

Comment: Thank you. What is the best way to handle such situation? The table is growing day by day, but always the most recent records are being selected.

Comment: Consider deleting rows or parking them somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try following things to speed up your query:**

```
1. Select only required column(s) instead of all (*) in SELECT Query.
2. Create Indexes on creation_time.
```